# Is there a better way to switch function without virtual function?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++. I have a base class, `Base`, and its derived class, `Derived`. And they are `push_back` into `std::vector<Base*> vec`. Assuming `vec[0] == &Base` and `vec[1] == &Derived`, I can switch function for `vec[0]` and `vec[1]` without virtual function. The code is at the end of this question. Is there better way to do it without virtual function? I want pure data classes and I want to add non-member functions to modify them to avoid modifying code of data classes. Thank you very much.

```
class TypeInterface {
public:
    virtual int type(void) = 0;
    virtual ~TypeInterface() {}
};

class Base : public TypeInterface {
public:

    static constexpr int type_ = 1;
    virtual int type(void) {
        return type_;
    }

    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:

    static constexpr int type_ = 10;
    virtual int type(void) {
        return type_;
    }

    virtual ~Derived() {};
};

void Function(Base* ptr) {
    std::cout << "function for Base" << std::endl;
}

void Function(Derived* ptr) {
    std::cout << "function for Derived" << std::endl;
}

void SwitchFunction(int type, void* ptr) {
    switch (type) {
    case 1: {
        Base* original_type_ptr = static_cast<Base*>(ptr);
        Function(original_type_ptr);
        break;
    }
    case 10: {
        Derived* original_type_ptr = static_cast<Derived*>(ptr);
        Function(original_type_ptr);
        break;
    }
    default:
        std::cout << "invalid type(=" << type << ")" << std::endl;
    }
}

void test_function_selecter(void) {

    Base b;
    Derived d;

    std::vector<Base*> vec;

    vec.push_back(&b);
    vec.push_back(&d);

    for (auto e: vec) {
        SwitchFunction(e->type(), e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour. Those are some nasty casts. Ideally, when you're just learning C++ you shouldn't use pointers or casts at all...

Comment: How about storing the function as a variable? You can make it static if it is used for all instances. std::function<void ()> myFunc = [] (void) {// do something}

Comment: Thank you, Kerrek SB. I tried to find what is your concern, and I suppose you may be afraid that I may use wrong combination of type and void*. In my case, SwitchFunction(e->type(), e) has fixed format. So I hope I can avoid selecting wrong combination.

Comment: Thank you, Striker. I hope I could understand your solution now. If I misunderstand your way, forgive me. I am a little bit afraid that your way needs to provide some pointers to the data class when input/output of function are different. And if I try multiple-threads, does it have racing problem?  Again, thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need 'type_', or 'int type(void)' instead use 'typeid'

```
void SwitchFunction(Base* ptr)
{
    auto&& type = typeid(*ptr);
    if (type == typeid(Base))
        Function(dynamic_cast<Base*>(ptr));
    else if (type == typeid(Derived))
        Function(dynamic_cast<Derived*>(ptr));
    else std::cout << "invalid type(=" << type.name() << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

Unfortunately this probably does not answer your question properly as it requires 'Base' to have a virtual function (such as a destructor, whish is generally recommended to be virtual whenever your type is involved in hierarchies)

Comment: Thank you, Issac. I am afraid I could not tell you my point. The point is I would like to add function to handle data class without modifying the data class. If I use virtual class, I need to add(and modify) virtual function to the data class. So virtual destructor is ok for me. Thank you for your solution again. But let me ask you a little bit more. In the view of speed performance, which one, your way or my way, is better or are they same?

Comment: &more there probably about the same, but if you really care I'd suggest testing it, personally I wouldn't bother, unless the number of types you have is really large, in which case the 'switch' statement may out perform the 'if/else if' statements (you can't use 'switch' with a  'typeid'), of course my solution takes up less space in your objects, which is probably more important than minor performance differences.